# Insert statement using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert some rows into the existing database in a Postgres database. I am using sqlalchemy to connect to the database and insert values. I can execute 'SELECT' statements but I couldn't figure out a way to insert values

I tried this

I have a table called 'COUNTRIES' with columns 'COUNTRY_ID' and 'NAME' there is a COLUMN called 'ID' which is the primary key but it gets dynamically assigned and no need to provide it when giving it in an INSERT statement

```
engine = create_engine(
        'postgres://' + database_user + ":" + database_password + "@" + database_host + ":" + database_port + "/" + database_name)


    # define meta information
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
    country_table = Table('countries', metadata, autoload=True)



    # insert
    i = insert(country_table)
    i = i.values({"country_id": "slytherin", "name": "Slytherin"})
    print session.execute(i)
```

Comment: Did you commit?

Comment: No I haven't done that. What would be the command to edit?

Comment: `session.commit()` :)

Comment: Thank you all =) that solved the issue, I kept trying all day just didn't commit it